# Обновление базы данных через определенное время

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Здравствуйте!

Пытаюсь написать код, который будет обновлять поле в базе данных, например через 10 секунд. Соответственно это сработает только после обновления страницы.

В поле `expire_c` хранится время при котором свершилось определенное действие + к нему добавляется срок его хранения, т.е. `expire_c = time() + 60*60*24*7`. Затем, берется значение из поля `expire_c` и вычитается из него настоящее время, если меньше 0, то соответственно необходимо почистить поле `remember`на пустое значение.

Код:

```
function time_mysql(){
   global $connection;
   $expire_time = time();
   $query = "UPDATE `customers` SET `remember` = NULL WHERE `expire_c` - '$expire_time' < ('$expire_time' - INTERVAL 10 SECOND)";
   $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or die(mysqli_error());
}
```

К сожалению, он у меня не срабатывает.

Comment: используйте  cronjob

Comment: @L. Vadim Пример, пожалуйста. Не работал с cronjob. Да и лучше мой код поправить.

Comment: Проектируйте БД так что бы не надо было обновлять записи по таймеру. например просто получайте в запросах поле remember в виде `select if(expire_c < now(), NULL,remember) from table`. Для удобства можете сделать view в которой будет такое вычисляемое на ходу поле

Comment: и не пользуйтесь в запросах временем получаемым функцией php, гораздо удобнее использовать встроенную MySQL функцию `now()`

Comment: @Mike Так не пойдет. В этом поле хранится время сессии. Мне необходимо очищать по таймеру истекшие сессии.

Comment: @Mike Случай когда сессия истекла и пользователь включил браузер и сессии этой нет в браузере естественно, соответсвенно обращение по коду моему не идет к ней, так как она закончилась, поэтому она висит в базе данных. А точне у меня записывается кука а не сессия. Вот почему она остается висеть в базе данных - `if( !isset($_COOKIE['hash']) ) return;`. Эта кука создается, когда пользователь отметил "запомнить меня" при входе в свою учетную запись. Зачем Лишний раз посылать запрос к БД, если куки нет в браузере.

Comment: И, если по Вашему сделать, то удаляться она будет только тогда, когда пользователь вновь зайдет в учетную запись, то есть выполнится обращение на проверку при входе в учетную запись. А так она будет висеть в БД пока он не зайдет. У меня, конечно, проверяется время сессии, если попытаются украсть и время истекло то она не восстановится.

Comment: @Mike Я думаю, что это все же лишнее место занимает, по 3-м полях идет привязка: 1. Версия браузера 2. Время куки 3. id куки 4. Возможно по ip будет (это хорошо, если статичный, но это опять же маловероятно). Все это хранится в БД, если нажали запомнить при входе. Если это не так страшно, то думаю тогда можно забыть про это, но все же хотелось бы для себя уяснить, как пишутся таймеры по определенному времени. Cron и MySQL Event Schedule не хотел бы использовать. В интернете, как раз нашел INTERVAL, вот решил попробовать реализовать на INTERVAL.

Comment: @Mike попробовал на одном из сайтов подделать сессию, т.е. создать сессии. Создавал в таком же браузере только в приватном режиме. Не удалось восстановить сеанс учетной записи, интересно, как это защищено так у них, у себя я например на сайте так могу восстановиться по "краже" сессии в приватном окне того же браузера.

Comment: @Mike Это Вы про это (длина записи) -"Например, если конвертировать поле VARCHAR(20) в поле CHAR(20), то всегда будут заняты 20 байт вне зависимости от того, используются они или нет."

Comment: @Mike При выходе пользователя из учетной записи, если кука существует, она удаляется - очищаются все 3 поля на пустое значение. Решил так сделать для безопасности. Да, Вы заставили меня задуматься о 2-х устройствах, в моем случае не прокатит с 2-х, просто перезаписываться будет кука в БД:)

Comment: @Mike То есть, например, `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` записывать уже не в БД, а в сессию и проверять, если значение сессии не сходится `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` то прекратить действие (в случае кражи). Я правильно понял? И второй вопросик: USER_AGENT у каждого свой уникальный? или он может совпадать с кем-то?:)

Comment: @Mike Пытаюсь включить `session.use_strict_mode` в `php.ini`. То есть нужно просто добавить строчку - `session.use_strict_mode=1` ?

Comment: @Mike А зачем вы удалили свои сообщения? Столько полезной для меня информации было(

Comment: Я надеялся вы основные моменты запомнили. Формат stackoverflow не предполагает такой переписки. вопрос-ответ и все. комментарии только для уточнения деталей вопроса. данный ворох комментариев все равно бы удалил модератор, зачем давать ему дополнительную работу

Comment: @Mike Он бы не удалил, а перенес в чат, как это обычно делается (как я наблюдал). Да и я уже хотел перенести в чат переписку, чтобы здесь не висела.

Comment: @Mike Прошу прощения за еще один вопрос, я вас уже спрашивал, но вы, к сожалению, не ответили, сейчас надеюсь ответите:) Пытаюсь включить `session.use_strict_mode=1` в php.ini. Но строчки такой вообще не нахожу, поэтому вставляю сам. Версия php 5.3.13. Стоит denwer. Захожу в файл по пути: **WebServers/usr/local/php5/php.ini** Даже, если вставляю сам строчку, то не срабатывает она. Я как понял, если я пытаюсь подделать сессию во втором браузере, в первом браузере значение сессии должно поменяться. Информации не могу найти в интернете, по настройке этой опции.

Comment: Может вы тогда зададите отдельный вопрос. И если вы его хорошо сформулируете по крайней мере будет шанс, что его прочитает кто то знающий про настройки php. Если такой человек есть вряд ли он читает комментарии к текущему вопросу